"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" on *installed* package
In my project I have an installed package, which I developed myself.  When trying to import functions from this package and then try to run the code, I get the above error.  This started just after I restructured the directories into a more "regular" configuration (I've been learning as I go, so things have been a bit of a mess).
[BACKGROUND: you may want to skip this part.
This project started off very small, and has been growing as I add more to it.  It is based in Flask, so the main code is in app.py; I had created several dozen functions as helpers.  As I learned, I found I could pull these off into a separate file and import them, and then that I could create a library package to distribute in case someone else in my company needed them.  This had all worked reasonably well, and I was able to reference the installed package. However, as part of my effort to move this into source control, I created a new directory structure (main Projects directory, separate subdirectories for the project UTILS_DEV and SPECIAL_FUNCTIONSLIB package, at the same level).  Therefore, the original package code is not where it was - but I didn't think that should matter if the package was installed and included into the library directories.]
I have tried the following import lines:
import special_functionslib
from special_functions import *
from special_functionslib.special_functions import *
from special_functions import func1, func2, func3
from SPECIAL_FUNCTIONSLIB.special_functions import func1, func2, func3
from ..SPECIAL_FUNCTIONSLIB.special_functions import func1, func2, func3

The actual code file is /export/home/dlevey/Projects/UTILS_DEV/app.py, and the package code is in /export/home/dlevey/Projects/SPECIAL_FUNCT IONSLIB/special_functions.py.  I can verify that the package is installed (in both the system and my library directories) by running 'sudo pip list' and 'pip list', respectively.  I can also see it when typing:



installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in installed_packages])
for package in installed_packages_list:
...     print(package)



in the Python console.  However, for some reason it does NOT show as available in the Python console entering help('modules') - I would imagine it is for the same reason.  Each of the above import commands, by the way, fails in the console.
I am sure that more info is needed, but I don't know what.  Please let me know what more I can provide.
As you can see, I tried specifying package name module (code file) name, and relative path info - none of it has helped.  I still get exactly the same error when trying to invoke the app.py file.  I do see similar questions which have been answered by discussing directory structure, but none of them are dealing with built and installed packages, only local code.
[UPDATE: 17-Oct 15:20 UTC]
When I installed, I did so using pip, pointing to the .whl file.  I did so twice in succession, to ensure that this was available not only to my local user but to any user.  As a result, the package is listed twice:
/export/home/dlevey/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/special_functionslib-0.8.7.dist-info
/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/special_functionslib-0.8.7.dist-info

This was as I expected.  Both of those directories re in my sys.path:
Python 3.12.6 (main, Sep  9 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 14.2.1 20240801 (Red Hat 14.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib64/python312.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.12', '/usr/lib64/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/export/home/dlevey/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.12/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
>>> import special_functionslib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'special_functionslib'
>>>

Not sure what else to check - is there something in the setup of the package itself which will not allow itself to be imported? Within that directory I see 7 entries, which appear to be the same filenames as for other packages.
